# JSON object model not utilizing JsonProperty names

Tags: json, ajax, .net-core, razor-pages

How do I get the component factory to bind and resolve to the JSON property attribute names, in an AJAX request to Razor action result?
Right now, I have a workaround where I just send the JSON string and deserialize it server-side, but thinking there must be a way for the action to do this.

For example, I have the following model:

```
public class ExampleClass 
{
    [JsonProperty("@first-name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("@last-name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I then try to send my model using the following script (note I have removed the double '@@' for razor view model binding to avoid confusion). This is the "rendered" script:

```
var model = {
        "@first-name": "test",
        "@last-name": "test"
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Dashboard?handler=test',
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("RequestVerificationToken", $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        },
        success: function (result) {

        },
        error: function (result) {
        }
    });
```

On my handler, I then get a null object (model values are null)

> public IActionResult OnPostTest([FromBody] ExampleClass model)

If I change the model to the following, everything works fine:

```
var model = {
        "FirstName": "test",
        "LastName": "test"
    };
```

I can see the object is getting passed correctly
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a silly mistake... I was using Newtonsoft.Json library attribute property binding (JsonProperty), instead of the serializer factory being used by the action (JsonPropertyName) in System.Text.Json.Serialization... very silly moment. Realized once I removed the Newtonsoft import and saw my class now had errors,

Now working...

```
public class ExampleClass 
{
    [JsonPropertyName("@first-name")]
    public int FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("@last-name")]
    public int LastName { get; set; }
}
```